# Using char instead of an String for end a do while loop. It's possible? Java

Tags: java, string, char

So in this do while code the boolean is an input of the user, but it's only needed one input. If the user press [c] the do while continues but if press any other key stops. I have already the code to do with a `String c = "";` but I want to be done with a `char`. 
Also the other problem happens when I use `char c [];` it's not possible to use the `c = kb.next().toUpperCase();`

Here is the exemple code I did.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String c = "";

do {
     //some code.
     //here asks to the user to continue or not.
     System.out.println("Press [c] to continue, any key to exit.");

     c = kb.next().toUpperCase();
} while ( c.equals == ("C") );
```

Maybe it's already aswered I tried to find an answer... Maybe I'm to Junior. But I wan't to know how I can do it. (please if it's already duplicate tell me don't unvote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use `char c` instead of `String c`, this code:

```
char c;
do {
     System.out.println("Press [c] to continue, any key to exit.");
     c = kb.next(".").toUpperCase().charAt(0);
} while (c == 'C');
```

The idea is to pass `"."` to `next(...)` method to consume exactly one character.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, very close. You need to compare strings using the String.equals, or String.equalsIgnoreCase rather than what you attempted. Refer to [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String c = "";

    do {
        //some code.
        //here asks to the user to continue or not.
        System.out.println("Press [c] to continue, any key to exit.");

        c = kb.next().toUpperCase();
    } while (!c.equalsIgnoreCase("C"));
}
```

---

With chars

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    char chr;

    do {
        //some code.
        //here asks to the user to continue or not.
        System.out.println("Press [c] to continue, any key to exit.");

        chr = kb.next().toCharArray()[0];
    } while (chr != 'c');
}
```

Comment: I want to use a `char` instead of a `String`

Comment: It's in the answer, sorry I missed that part.

Comment: Okey but now the thinks is, if the user input _C_ ? It's gonna start again.

Comment: Because of the **chr != 'c'** condition, you just need to change it to **chr == 'c'**